# find the similar string(obj.key) from two array, arr[{},{}] arr2[{},{}],then set checked attribute to true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

Thanks for your time. there are two arrays, the arr is the dropdownlist in the html page which could be multiple select. when submit, the controller do operations on the selected values got from arr  **commodity = councils_item.replace(/(.*)_/, a => '')**  And finally generated a new array which format is arr2. That results some words in arr are composed of the words from commodities in arr2. such as **ITPSM** in arr2 is similar to **TechProd_ITPSM** in arr. How could I find the elements in arr which is similar to the element arr2/commodities or the same ones such as **Travel.** And set the corresponding item **checked** attribute value to true? I'm using angularjs and angular material. Thanks a million in advance.  By the way below is part of html as well.

```
var arr = [
    { label: 'Techod_ITSM', checked: false },
    { label: 'Techod_Teco', checked: false },
    { label: 'Techod_Connectivity', checked: false },
    { label: 'Services_CF', checked: false },
    { label: 'Technical Services', checked: false },
    { label: 'Travel', checked: false },
    { label: 'Marketing & solutions', checked: false },
    { label: 'All', checked: false },
    { label: 'facility Solution Services', checked: false }
];
var arr2 = [
    { "Marketing & Communications": true },
    { "All": true },
    { "Travel": true },
    { "Technical Products": true, "commodities": ["ITSM", "Teco", "Connectivity"] },
    { "Services": true, "commodities": ["CF", "Technical Services"] }
];

<form name="userForm" novalidate ng-submit="userForm.$valid &&  userProject.createProject()"> 
<md-select ng-model="userProject.project_councils" multiple="true">
 <md-option ng-value="project_councils" ng-repeat="project_councils in project_councilss" ng-selected="project_councils.checked">{{project_councils.label}}
</md-option></md-select>
<md-button type="submit" id="createProject" value="Submit" class="md-raised md-primary" aria-label="Create" > Submit
</md-button>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERTpw.png)

Answer (score 0):

At `change` event of `<select>` you can use `for..of` loop to iterate `arr2` array, iterate each object property, value using `Object.entries()`, check if property value contains text of selected `<option>` with `RegExp` `/[A-Z][a-z]+/g` to match uppercase letter followed by one or more lower case letters; if property is `"commodities"`, concatenate the array value of the object to current `"label"` as a string with `.join("")`; iterate `arr` using `for..of` loop, `Object.entries()`, set `checked` of `arr` at current index to `true` if `"label"` property of `arr` contains a match to `select` `.value` using same `RegExp`.

```js
var arr = [
    { label: 'TechProd_ITPSM', checked: false },
    { label: 'TechProd_Telco', checked: false },
    { label: 'TechProd_Connectivity', checked: false },
    { label: 'Services_CWF', checked: false },
    { label: 'Technical Services', checked: false },
    { label: 'TechProd_Telco', checked: false },
    { label: 'Travel', checked: false },
    { label: 'Marketing & solutions', checked: false },
    { label: 'All', checked: false },
    { label: 'Facility Solution Services', checked: false }
];
var arr2 = [
    { "Marketing & Communications": true },
    { "All": true },
    { "Travel": true },
    { "Technical Products": true, "commodities": ["ITPSM", "Telco", "Connectivity"] },
    { "Services": true, "commodities": ["CWF", "Business Services", "Technical Services"] }
];

const select = document.querySelector("select");
const re = /[A-Z][a-z]+/g;

select.onchange = () => {
  const val = select.value.match(re);
  filter: for (let prop of arr2) {
    for (let [key, value, c] of Object.entries(prop)) {
      if (new RegExp(val.join("|")).test(key)) {
        if (/commodities/.test(key)) c = value.join("");
        for (let [index, {label}] of Object.entries(arr)) {
          arr[index]["checked"] = new RegExp(label.concat(c || "").match(re)
                                  .join("|")).test(select.value);
        }              
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

for (let {label, checked} of arr) {
  let option = new Option(label, label);
  option.selected = checked;
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select><option value="">Select an option</option></select>
```

Comment: Hi AJT_82, I could understand your approach, but not familiar with with those functions currently. Thus,  I tried to select TechProd_ITPSM, but all the TechProd_Telco and TechProd_Connectivity checked attribute were set as true as well. The desirable result is that only the element TechProd_ITPSM  was checked. The other two should be false. Could you please help to take a look further?

Comment: _"How could I find the elements in arr which is similar"_ Why did you include term "similar" at Question?

Comment: @TammyShi  Are you only trying to set `checked` to `true` at `arr` based on selection and `arr` alone? What role does `arr2` have in procedure?

Comment: I used angular material   md-select  for user to  multiple select values from the dropdown list, and got a result  from DB when user perform edit action. Trying to set the checked attribute as true if the items in dorpdown is exist in responsed arr2. I've used track by $value:id, but do not know how to make it work for multiple selection.  That's another question from me.

Comment: <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="">
                        <label>Councils</label>
                        <md-select ng-model="userProject.project_councils" multiple="true">
                            <md-option ng-value="project_councils" ng-repeat="project_councils in project_councilss" ng-selected="project_councils.checked">
                            {{project_councils.label}}
                            </md-option>
                        </md-select>
                    </md-input-container>

Comment: yes, but I'd like to get some general function which could be used not only three of them.

Comment: Have not tried angular material. The function at `change` handler can be adjusted to match more than three strings at `arr2`, as initial Answer demonstrated. What is the match pattern and logic?

Comment: example arr(dropdown in html only label displayed) have 9 items and each one is like  { label: 'Techod_ITSM', checked: false }, user select one/two/ or three but saved in another model arr2. "Technical Products": true, "commodities": ["ITSM", "Teco", "Connectivity"]     your can see the label in arr is splited in attributes:  Techod =>Technical Products and ITSM => ITSM. now I have gain respond arr2, want to show the check box in html is displayed as ITSM is selected. others are not.

Comment: Why are arrays structured differently? Can you include exact description of expected matches and associated logic between `arr` and `arr2` at  Question?

Answer (score 0):

fixed. use forEach to get all commodities and then use map and reduce to deal with a "join" string "TechProd_ITPSM" to set the checked value as true.
There would be better approach. Welcome any of your idea.

```
var selectedCom = "";
            var selectedComArr = [];
            feedbackProject.project_councils.forEach(function(resCouncils) {
                var resCommodities = resCouncils.commodities;
                if (resCommodities) {
                    resCommodities.forEach(function(resComItem) {
                        if ((resComItem == "ITPSM") || (resComItem == "Telco") || (resComItem == "Connectivity")) {
                            selectedCom = "TechProd_" + resComItem;
                            selectedComArr.push(selectedCom);
                        } else if ((resComItem == "CWF") || (resComItem == "Business Services") || (resComItem == "Technical Services")) {
                            selectedCom = "Services" + resComItem;
                            selectedComArr.push(selectedCom);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    selectedComArr.push(Object.keys(resCouncils)[0]);
                }
                console.log(selectedComArr);
            });

            function reducer(map, that) {
                map[that.label] = that;
                return map;
            }

            function getMapper(map) {
                return function(item) {
                    var temp = map[item];
                    if (temp && temp.label === item) {
                        temp.checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            function checkSelected(arr, arr2) {
                var map = arr.reduce(reducer, {});
                arr2.map(getMapper(map));

            };
```